# While loop / java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm doing a program which has two different questions, ohm and ampere to be exact.

I know how to make this work but the problem is that in the end one more question should pop up asking "do u want to make a new calculation?" this question should work like if I press "Y" the program should continue from the beginning and if I press "N" the program should exit.

I hope anyone got some ideas that could help me finish this. And the program has to be in JOptionpane.dialog/message format.

//delajz

this is what i got atm.

```
//Declaring Variables

Ampere = Integer.parseInt(FragaAm);
Ohm = Integer.parseInt(FragaOhm);

//koden
do
{
    FragaAm =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hur många Ampere? ");
    FragaOhm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("hur hög resistans? ");
    svar = Ohm*Ampere; //calculate
    slutsvar = svar + "Volt"; //answer
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,slutsvar);    

    borjaom =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Igen? J eller N " ); // the question which ask for new calc
} while ( borjaom == "j" ||borjaom == "J" );
```

Comment: If you could add some of your code, that might help us determine exactly what you need. Just make sure to indent lines of code by 4 spaces when you post it so that it gets formatted properly on SO.

Comment: Do you have an embryo of the code or do you wan't someone two write the code for you?

Comment: Is this homework?  And are you sure you're using JavaScript, not Java Swing?

Comment: Sounds like a mis-categorized homework assignment. JOptionPane is a Java/Swing class.

Comment: `JOptionPane` is in the Java API. Are you sure you don't mean Java?

Comment: yes it is a homework. last test for the season, and im stuck on this one.. i'll add some code

Comment: thanks to vonc andR. Bemrose. its now working .D i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can start by looking the Sun article [How to Make Dialogs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).
It mentions a `JOptionPane` configured like the one you are looking to make:

[image]

```
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
    "The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
    + "pressing one of the following buttons.\n"
    + "Do you understand?",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: The problem calls for pressing "Y" or "N" not a button labeled Yes or No.

Comment: yea brandon, from the beginning that was my problem. but it was just a way of explaining that i needed something to call a restart of the program or a exit. this works just as good

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
borjaom =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Igen? J eller N " );
```

Also, `JOptionPane` **can only be used to input Strings**.  So all of your variables that you set to receive the input from the JOptionPane should be declared as Strings.  *Ampere* and *Ohm* should be declared as integers while *FragaAm*, *FragaOhm* and *borjaom* should be declared as Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your while condition:

```
} while ( borjaom == "j" ||borjaom == "J" );
```

assumes strings can be compared on object basis, while this is true in case the strings are interned, it is better to either switch to an enum integer that represents the Yes/No result or use the equals methods from `String` like:

```
} while ("J".equalsIgnorecase(borjaom));
```

(using this format instead of `borjaom.equalsIgnorecase("J")` has the advantage that it handles the situation where `borjoam == null` correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what VonC said, in JOptionPane.dialog/message format:

```
//Declaring Variables
int borjaom = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;

// omitted other code, but it should still be here

    // Note that borjaom is an int now
    borjaom = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Igen?", "Title goes here", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE ); // the question which ask for new calc

  } while ( borjaom == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION );
```

borjaom will be set to one of `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION` or `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`.

Oh, and if you want a title-less dialog (or with the default title), change `"Title goes here"` to `null`

Answer (score 0):

This part will not work correctly:

```
    Ampere = Integer.parseInt(FragaAm);
    Ohm = Integer.parseInt(FragaOhm);

    do
    {
        FragaAm =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hur många Ampere? ");
        FragaOhm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("hur hög resistans? ");
```

You are converting `FragaAm` to an integer before reading it.
you must first read it and then convert:

```
    do
    {
        FragaAm =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hur många Ampere? ");
        Ampere = Integer.parseInt(FragaAm);
        FragaOhm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("hur hög resistans? ");
        Ohm = Integer.parseInt(FragaOhm);
```

and please have a look at the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/index.html) ,
in your case: variables starts with lowercase (*only* convention, but used around the whole world)